# Do we put something inside parentheses just because we want to able to call a method?

Tags: c#, methods, user-input

When I call the `Check` method, I put "5" in parentheses. I do it because it requires an integer to call the method. Does this have anything to do with user input, or is it a necessary thing to be able to call method?

How can I not put something in parenthesis, but still be able to call the `Check` method?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Check(5);
    Console.Read();
}

public static void Check(int myInt)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to checkc if it is odd or even number: ");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    int userInputNum;
    int parsedValue;

    if (Int32.TryParse(userInput, out userInputNum))
    {
        parsedValue = userInputNum;
    }
    else
    {
        parsedValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a number or anything.");
    }

    if ((parsedValue % 2) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is a even number.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It is an odd number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-access

Comment: Putting things in paranthess is indeed how one normally passes arguments to methods. Why do you not want to do that?

Comment: I assume you're just asking out of curiosity and don't have an actual problem am I right? This isn't a good question for this site, but I'm sure if you Googled you could find plenty of resources on how programming syntax has evolved and why. TL;DR - C# evolved from C++ which evolved from C which evolved from B (which probably almost no one alive has ever used). I imagine the parenthesis syntax dates back to B if not earlier. Also it's similar to how in math we use parenthesis to encapsulate function arguments like sin and cos.

Comment: Consider rearranging your methods so that `Check` has a _single responsibility_. And that is to "check" some input for some conditions. That does not include retrieving that input from the user. Now, passing an argument suddenly makes sense, right? And further: maybe now it also makes sense to _return_ the result of the check?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? Stack Overflow was launched nearly 15 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `public static void Check(int myInt)` method states it accepts a mandatory `int` parameter and calls it `myInt`.

Because of this, wherever you want to call the `Check` method, you have to provide a value for this parameter: `Check(5)`, `Check(100)`, `Check(Random.Shared.NextInt())` and so on.

It is illegal to call the method without a value for its parameter, i.e. `Check()`.

Now, the method `Check` accepts a mandatory parameter `int myInt`, but it doesn't actually use it anywhere. Since the parameter is useless, you may as well remove it from the method requirements.

```
public static void Check()
{
...
```

Once you remove the `int myInt` parameter from the method signature, you no longer have to provide a value for that parameter when you call the method. You call parameterless methods with simply `Check()` in your code.